# Montando array com checkbox

Tags: javascript, array, asp

Gostaria de amadurecer a ideia abaixo de mandar uma váriavel em JavaScript para o asp e com as escolhas num `array`, só estou conseguindo mandar uma escolha no momento:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getElements()
{
var choices = [];
var els = document.getElementsByName('vehicle');
for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
  if ( els[i].checked ) {
    choices.push(els[i].value);
    var resultado = choices[i];
    //alert(resultado);
    document.location.href = 'GetElementByName.asp?resultado=' + resultado;
  }
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car<br>

<input type="button" onclick="getElements()" value="How many elements named ?">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<%
pega_resultado = request.queryString("resultado")
Response.Write ">" & pega_resultado
%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando tens vários inputs com o mesmo nome então precisas de juntar `[]` para serem tratados como array. Ou seja:

```
name="vehicle[]"
```

E para isto não é preciso JavaScript. Basta usar a `form`:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="GetElementByName.asp">
```

(atenção às IDs duplicadas no HTML)

De qualquer maneira o problema real no JavaScript que tens é que estás a fazer `document.location.href` dentro do `for` e esse código faz a página abrir com o link indicado, sem terminar o loop.

Corrigindo o código poderia ser por exemplo:

```js
function getElements() {
    var choices = [];
    var els = document.getElementsByName('vehicle');
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        if (els[i].checked) choices.push(els[i].value);
    }
    var resultado = choices.join('_');
    alert(resultado);
    document.location.href = 'GetElementByName.asp?resultado=' + resultado;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="getElements()" value="How many elements named ?">
</form>
```

Answer (score -4):

```js
function checkedToArrayNames(name){
    return [...document.getElementsByName(name+'[]')].filter(e=>e.checked).map(e=>e.value)
}

checkedToArrayNames('items')
```

```css
.grid{display: grid}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="Nome A" > Nome A
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="Nome B" > Nome B
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="Nome C" > Nome C
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="Nome D" > Nome D
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="Nome E" > Nome E
</div>

<div id="ar_list"></div>
<br>
<button onclick="ar_list.innerHTML = checkedToArrayNames('items')">render</button>
```